# При применении cvEncodeImage в приложении с открытми соккетами возникает ошибка Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, unix, opencv

Пытаюсь встроить opencv в сетевое приложение, почему то при открытом соккете возникает ошибка Segmentation fault. Хотя отдельно тот же самый код работает как часы. Работаю в Linux. Почему это может быть ?

Этот код просто берет кадр с веб камеры(сделал без цикла для теста) и преобразует его в jpg.

```
       CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
       IplImage* fr= nullptr;

       fr = cvQueryFrame( capture );
       auto temp = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", fr);
       uchar *a = temp->data.ptr;
       cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
```

ошибка на вот этой строчке

```
auto temp = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", fr);
```

Comment: У вас же явно `cvQueryFrame` не отрабатывает. Вы даже не проверяете валидность фрэйма и получаете разыменование nullptr.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, почему это может быть? Камера подрубается вроде

Comment: а это у вас нужно спросить - на форуме телепатов, которые по nullptr определяют состояние соеденения с камерой точно нет